# Correct way to return incomplete result in REST API?

Tags: json, rest, api-design

I have a REST API that aggregates data from several different sources, does some formatting, and provides it back in a JSON payload.

**/api/blah/resources**

```
[
    {
        "name": "resource1",
        "value": 19,
        "foo": "bar"
    },
    {
        "name": "resource2",
        "value": 68,
        "foo": "baz"
    },
    {
        "name": "resource3",
        "value": 88,
        "foo": "blee"
    }
    //etc...
]
```

However, some of the sources I am aggregating are unreliable, and requests to them can time out, fail, or get no response intermittently.

```
[
    {
        "name": "resource1",
        "value": 19,
        "foo": "bar"
    },
    //resource2 is missing :c
    {
        "name": "resource3",
        "value": 88,
        "foo": "blee"
    }
    //etc...
]
```

When part of this aggregation fails, what is the best/RESTful/correct way to inform the consumer of my REST api that the data they are requesting is incomplete?

Comment: I am not sure. Interesting question. Probably you should add a status property to the resources, so you could set a `status: "timeout"` or something like that on the missing remote resources.

Comment: I would, but I don't necessarily know which specific resources are missing in these error cases, so I cannot assume a placeholder in these cases.

Comment: I thought at least you know by which resources the timeout happened. Is it important from client perspective that some of the resources are not available?

Comment: In this case yes. Knowing that the aggregation was only partially successful is a critical piece of info for this specific use case, because it could cost a client money to make a decision without having all the information.

Comment: Then I think you need a different representation, something like: `{resources: [...], partial: true}`.

Comment: I actually like the idea of enveloping the resource, but the powers that be think that having the resource inside an envelope isn't very RESTful. They recommend using a custom HTTP header (X-Incomplete-Result) to accomplish what we want, but I am not sure about that either.

Comment: Actually this is a collection representation what we are talking about, and not a resource. The resource is something you cannot see or touch, it can have many different representations. This so called envelope technique is used in real REST systems e.g. https://www.w3.org/community/hydra/wiki/Collection_Design . I am not sure about your system, it is most probably not REST if you don't use hyperlinks and metadata in your response, or at least a vendor specific MIME type, but that's not my problem. If I were you I wouldn't worry about this so called "RESTful" thing.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you should use special [HTTP Status Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

**EDIT**

Thinking about my answer few years later made me look on this status codes list one more time. From what I see, I might argue as 202 might be the only reasonable way to go if we want to stick to status code.

> **202 Accepted -** The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed. The request might or might not be eventually acted upon, and may be disallowed when processing occurs

I could say: *accepted, that's your data to start with, but expect changes in future*

Comment: 206 Partial Content seemed like it had potential, but I think its intended for a specific use case of downloading parts of files off of some index sent by the client. In my use case, it doesn't feel correct because I am not actually requesting a range or downloading parts of files, I am just getting incomplete content

Comment: @72A12F4E Yepp, afaik it is for serving range requests, so it does not solve your problem.